# Card-deck with equal height on card items

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 card-deck in IE11 with equal height on card items.

I am trying to do [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRIGb.png) in IE11 as well, but in IE11 i looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmaT8.png). What am I missing? 
 It is important that the cards will keep the same height in the row they are.
 Or is it the wrong way to do it like this?
My html and css is like this:

```css
card-deck .card {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    width: calc((33.33%) - (30px));
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex: initial;
    -webkit-flex: initial;
    flex: initial;
  }
}

@media(max-width:991px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    width: calc((50%) - (30px));
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: initial;
  }
}

@media(max-width:575px) {
  .card-deck .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/288x200/" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/288x200/" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/288x200/" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/288x200/" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/288x200/" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.
```

Comment: read [bs4 support for ie](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/browsers-devices/#internet-explorer) and check [can-i-use](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex), click  __show all__ and __know issues__ maybe it will give you some answers.

Comment: I think you're better off defining flex-basis than width for the cards.

Comment: follow this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17310

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I have not solved the issue yet.